# Check if MySQL is still connected or disconnected

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, mysqli

Basically, what i'm trying to do in pseudo-code is this:

```
if button_1_press {
    if connection_doesnt_exist{
        create_connection
        echo "connected"
    }
    else {
        echo "still connected"
    }
}
if button_2_press{
    if connection_exist{
        close_connection
        echo "disconnected"
    }
    else {
        echo "still disconnected"
    }
}
```

I tryed some approaches, the best i have so far is this:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
        <title>PHP AJAX Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type='submit' onclick='makeRequest();' value='Connect' id='b1'/>
        <input type='submit' onclick='makeRequest();' value='Disconnect' id='b2'/>
        <div id='ResponseDiv'>
        This is a div to hold the response.
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var xmlHttp = createXMLHttpRequest();

function createXMLHttpRequest(){
    var xmlHttp;
    if (window.ActiveXObject){
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } 
        catch(e) {
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }
    else {
        try {
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } 
        catch(e) {
            xmlHttp = false;
        }   
    }
    if(!xmlHttp){
        alert("Error creating the XMLHttpRequest object.");
    }
    else{
        return xmlHttp;
    }
}


function makeRequest(){
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4){
            HandleResponse();
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("b1").onclick = function () {xmlHttp.open("GET", "mysql.php?button=1", true); xmlHttp.send(null);}
    document.getElementById("b2").onclick = function () {xmlHttp.open("GET", "mysql.php?button=2", true); xmlHttp.send(null);}
}

function HandleResponse(){
    response = xmlHttp.responseText;    
    document.getElementById('ResponseDiv').innerHTML = response;
}
```

PHP

```
<?php 

$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

if ($_GET['button']==1){
    if ($conn){
        echo "already connected";
        }
    else {
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
        echo " connected";
    }
}

if ($_GET['button']==2){
    if ($conn){
        echo "disconnected";
        $conn->close();
    }
    else {
        echo "still disconnected";
    }
}

?>
```

My problems are:

1) When any of the buttons is clicked for the first time, it does nothing; only starts working from the second click.

2) Button "Connected" always shows "already connected".

3) Button "Disconnect" always shows "disconnected"

What I understand is this happen because every time a button is pressed, the makeRequest function makes an AJAX call, which creates a mysqli connection every time, so at the moment of evaluate if its open, it always will be true, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Just pointing out, you're using "new mysqli" testing if it exists...then using "new mysqli" again if it doesn't (which will never happen)...redundant and as Marc B stated, pointless...

Answer (score 3):

This totally pointless.

By default PHP shuts down/cleans up all open connections when a script exits. So every time you do an AJAX request to test the db connection, you'd be opening a **NEW** database connection anyways, never testing a previous connection.

You COULD use persistent DB connections, but even with that there's no guarantee you'd get the SAME connection as you got last time. You'd get some randomish connection from a pool of open connections, which against is pointless to test.

And going with persistent connections opens a huge pile of problems as well. The microscopic benefits of going persistent is vastly dwarved by all the problems it'll cause.

Comment: There's always a method to someone's madness.

Comment: If the question was about *"How to make a connect/disconnect... "* method, then that would make more sense. Some like to play around with gadgets to see what buttons can do, when you push on 'em. *"What does this do?"*. - POOF.

Comment: I got your point. Sorry for my ignorance, I'm totally new using MySQL with PHP and I tryng to learn some concepts. So, if you dont mind explain me, how i should do to create a single connection, make some ajax calls for make some things, and be sure that when i make the ajax calls again, the same database connections remains?

Or the proper way to do this is when i make an AJAX call, open a new connection, do some things (return other things if is necessary), and close the connection? Thanks for your time :P

Comment: that's pretty much how all php scripts work. especially with mysql. connect to the db at the start of the script, do a bunch of stuff, then allow the connection to be closed when the script exits. mysql's connection protocol is pretty lightweight and isn't much of an overhead anyways, compared to some other dbs.